# Merge Material UI themes

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, themes

I'm merging two themes in Material UI like explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838973/merge-theme-configuration-settings-in-material-ui).

So I have these themes defined:

```
palette: {
    primary: {
            main: "#e50380"
        },
        secondary: {
            main: "#000"
        }
    },
    props: {
        MuiButtonBase: {
            disableRipple: true
        },
        MuiButton: {
            disableElevation: true,
            variant: "contained"
        },
    }
```

And the second from a json file:

```
    "palette": {
        "primary": {
            "main": "#06e503"
        },
        "secondary": {
            "main": "#ad976e"
        }
    }
```

The merge:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme(defaultTheme, userTheme);
```

It works as expected. The props are inherited from the first theme and the colors are overwritten by the second. But when I hover over my test buttons the colors of the first theme is used instead of the colors assigned in the second, why is this? My expectation would be that the hover color is calculated and used from the same color assigned in the second theme?

Comment: Please provide a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) reproducing your problem.

Comment: Code sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/usage-forked-y8ewu?file=/index.js

Comment: Your sandbox does not have any custom theme at all. Perhaps you forgot to save the latest version?

Comment: Ooops, what about now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hover styling for contained buttons with a color of primary or secondary leverages [theme.palette.primary.dark](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.3/packages/material-ui/src/Button/Button.js#L142) and [theme.palette.secondary.dark](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.3/packages/material-ui/src/Button/Button.js#L154). You are only overriding `primary.main` and `secondary.main`. The `dark` and `light` variations are filled in by `createMuiTheme` by a function called [augmentColor](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.3/packages/material-ui/src/styles/createPalette.js#L191). This function gets added to [theme.palette](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.3/packages/material-ui/src/styles/createPalette.js#L233) so that you can use it in your own code.

You can use `augmentColor` to fill in the additional colors in your overrides in the following manner:

```
const muiDefaultTheme = createMuiTheme();
const userTheme = {
  palette: {
    primary: muiDefaultTheme.palette.augmentColor({
      main: "#06e503"
    }),
    secondary: muiDefaultTheme.palette.augmentColor({
      main: "#ad976e"
    })
  }
};
```

[image: Edit override colors in theme]