# How to get Material-UI V5 to auto-generate :hover colors in custom color objects for buttons

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using MUI v5 (latest) to specify custom colors for use in my theme provider. However, I've noticed that there's no hover state color change. Is there a specific value I need to add to `main` to get it to auto generate the hues/colors? From my memory, it auto-generated hover states on custom colors. What do I need to do?

My theme file:

```
import { createTheme, responsiveFontSizes } from "@material-ui/core"

let theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    palette: {
      sand: {
        main: '#f3d3bd'
      }
    },
    thin: {
      fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
      fontWeight: 100,
      fontStyle: 'sans-serif',
    },
    fontFamily: [
      'Roboto',
      '-apple-system',
      'BlinkMacSystemFont',
      '"Segoe UI"',
      '"Helvetica Neue"',
      'Arial',
      'sans-serif',
      '"Apple Color Emoji"',
      '"Segoe UI Emoji"',
      '"Segoe UI Symbol"',
    ].join(','),
    
  },
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#0277bd',
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#b2ff59',
    },
    darkGray: {
      main: '#333333'
    },
    lightGray: {
      main: '#5e5e5e'
    },
    amber: {
      main: '#f96225',
    },
    turquoise: {
      main: '#48e5c2'
    },
    sand: {
      main: '#f3d3bd'
    },
    offWhite: {
      main: '#fcfaf9'
    }
  },
})

theme = responsiveFontSizes(theme)
export default theme
```

Comment: Hover colors aren't part of the theme. They are generated within the components where they are applicable. What component are you trying to use a custom color for where you don't see the hover effect? It would also help to include a sandbox that reproduces the lack of the hover effect.

Comment: It doesn't matter the component { Button, IconButton, etc }. Using MUI v5 with a custom color variant doesn't give hover states unless I explicitly create `light` and `dark` properties on the custom color objects. I'll see about setting up a sandbox, as my code is local, so I'd have to strip some stuff out. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Material-UI does not automatically augment custom colors that you add to the palette with light and dark variations, but it does [augment the standard colors](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v5.0.0-alpha.37/packages/material-ui/src/styles/createPalette.js#L251). These light and dark variations are used for some hover effects such as [contained Button](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v5.0.0-alpha.37/packages/material-ui/src/Button/Button.js#L128).

You can use the `augmentColor` function in `theme.palette` to add generated versions of the light and dark variations to your color (or specify them explicitly):

```
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

const defaultTheme = createTheme();
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    green: defaultTheme.palette.augmentColor({
      color: { main: "#00ff00" },
      name: "green"
    })
  }
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Button variant="contained" color="green">
        Hello
      </Button>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit augment custom color]

Related answer: [Merge Material UI themes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65993328/merge-material-ui-themes/65996812#65996812)

Comment: Do you have tips on how to find that stuff? I searched the docs, and I couldn't find out how to do this. It was *way* easier to just add light and dark variations, but for some reason, I read somewhere how it converted the colors to hsl values and it would adjust the values [600]/etc

Comment: My main tip is to dig into the source code when you can’t find an answer in the docs. Even when you do find an answer in the docs, go to the source code and try to follow exactly how a particular prop works. Gradually you’ll get more familiar with how the code is structured and it will get a little easier to dig into the next question that comes up.